# What Android Stock Apps are replaceable through ADB?

Tags: applications

What's the list of stock android apps that a user can replace on their phone?

e.g. could I replace **com.android.keyguard** to change my lock screen? i.e. Write my own version of it.

I am running Android 8.
A list of replaceable apps could really help.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Unless you specify Android phone and Android version you are using, your question is rather too broad and too varied to be answered precisely. Please narrow it down.

Comment: Unless you have a rooted phone system applications can't be replaced at all.

Comment: I've read somewhere on XDA that it's possible by uninstalling the system app and then *adb install newapp.apk* and it takes the position of the previously uninstalled app.